# How 'memory efficient doubly linked list' works?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, xor-linkedlist, mem.-efficient-linkedlist

In [Data Structures and Algorithms Made Easy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1468108867), `struct` of memory efficient memory list given as follows,

```
struct LinkNode
{
 int data;
 struct LinkNode* ptrdiff;
}
```

In `ptrdiff`, there will be xoring of previous and next node is done. For example, previous node have address **100** and next node address is **500**.

So, in ptrdiff address will be **400**. Now how it is possible to move to next or previous node (as we do in doubly link list), just by knowing xoring of their addresses?

Am I missing any step here?

Comment: Why not actually read the book? We don't just know the xor of the addresses, we also know the address of the previous (or next) node.

Comment: Where you know addresses of next and previous node?

Comment: You start with the list header, which is both the previous node of the first node and the next node of the last node. As you traverse the list, you always have the address of one node back. Maybe the book doesn't mention that -- the reviews indicate that the book is trash. Do yourself a favor, burn it, and get a real data structures book ... or learn to search and use the web: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_linked_list (which says to use 0 as the initial previous or next pointer, which works fine).

Comment: "memory efficient doubly linked list" is a contradiction in itself. The two pointers that are generally used to link them are only part of the story. The other part is the memory overhead of allocating all those small objects. A `LinkNode` will occupy at least four pointers worth of memory due to allocation overhead and alignment constraints, i. e. on a 64 bit system you still use at least 32 bytes to store one 4 byte value!

Comment: The above comment is nonsense. In modern mallocs there is no memory overhead for very small blocks ... they are allocated from pages devoted to blocks of that size, so the low order bits of the address identify the size. And they are quantized ... with a pool of 16-byte entries, adding another pointer will **double** the memory needed, so the XOR version is indeed memory-efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first node has no previous node, and the last node has no next node ... so think of the address of the node before the first and of the node after the last as 0. That's enough to start a traversal, and as you traverse you always have the address of the preceding node in hand so you can determine the address of the succeeding node. Here's an example of traversing such a list and printing the data ... pass the address of either the first or last node to printxorlist and it will print it either forwards or backwards:

```
void printxorlist(struct LinkNode* node)
{
    struct LinkNode* prev = NULL;
    while (node)
    {
        printf("%d\n", node->data);
        struct LinkNode* next = (struct LinkNode*)((intptr_t)node->ptrdiff ^ (intptr_t)prev);
        prev = node;
        node = next;
    }
}
```

Note that we have to cast `node->ptrdiff` because it doesn't really have the right type. Better would be to declare it correctly:

```
struct LinkNode
{
    int data;
    intptr_t ptrdiff;
}
```

then

```
void printxorlist(struct LinkNode* node)
{
    struct LinkNode* prev = NULL;
    while (node)
    {
        printf("%d\n", node->data);
        struct LinkNode* next = (struct LinkNode*)(node->ptrdiff ^ (intptr_t)prev);
        prev = node;
        node = next;
    }
}
```

Comment: That means anyway we are keeping 2 addresses, though one is temporary.

Comment: @PranitKothari Keeping a temporary is an oxymoron. Each node of the list only contains one pointer field, not two. While traversing the list, we *use* three pointer variables: the previous node, the current node, and the next node.

Comment: `The first node has no previous node, and the last node has no next node` - this works perfectly fine for circular lists.

Comment: @greybeard Doubly linked circular lists don't have much use, and with XORed lists would require maintaining a pair of pointers to two consecutive nodes in order to start traversal, so no, it's not "perfectly fine".

Answer (score 0):

In this type of linked list, you can not traverse from the address of any arbitrary node. Because you need some extra information either about predecessor address or successor address. But traversing from the first node(predecessor address =0 , since not any predecessor) or last node(successor address=0, since not any successor) is possible.

Comment: There's an echo in here.